# Enabling/disabling a JButton by another JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've got JButtons "Pause" and "Unpause". When a user pauses the program, the Pause button  should be disabled and the Unpause button should be enabled. I don't know how to write it. The unpause button works, but the Pause button doesn't, because "unpause cannot be resolved". How to deal with it? There's my code:

```
final JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");

    pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Url.pauseThread();
                pause.setEnabled(false); //this works
                unpause.setEnabled(true); //this does NOT work - "not resolved"

            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  

        }
    });

    final JButton unpause = new JButton("Unpause");

    unpause.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Url.resumeThread();
                pause.setEnabled(true); // this works
                unpause.setEnabled(false); // this works
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Judging from the code posted, it's unresolved because it is only local to the method (I'm assuming you have an `init` method or the code posted above is in your constructor). Try globally declaring your buttons; that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare pause and unpause button and then add listeners.

```
final JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
final JButton unpause = new JButton("Unpause");
    pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Url.pauseThread();
                pause.setEnabled(false); //this works
                unpause.setEnabled(true); //this does NOT work - "not resolved"

            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  

        }
    });



    unpause.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Url.resumeThread();
                pause.setEnabled(true); // this works
                unpause.setEnabled(false); // this works
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Basically, you were calling `setEnabled` from unpause button in pause button listener before unpause button was even declared.

Comment: Or, I'm assuming there are multiple `JButton`s in his class, you should have also suggested that his class should implement `ActionListener` and just check to see what `JButton` it's on as opposed to creating a new `ActionListener` for each `JButton`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll accept in 7 minutes. I'll also consider implementing of ActionListener. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @JoshM No Josh, I personally consider that as a bad practice. If you want to implement `ActionListener` directly in class, then create separate, so called "controller" class, which implements `ActionListener` and put your logic there. Just a personal opinion.

Comment: @brano88 How is it bad practice?

Comment: @JoshM Because I'm mostly "beaten" by amount of "defensive programming" code. To protect my code from becoming "spaghetti" code, I create separate classes which implement some kind of listener.